# Reading Data from SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to read data from each cell of database. If the corresponding value is encountered then I have increment a variable count for that corresponding variable.

Consider the following table

```
Ques1   Ques2   Ques3   Ques4   Ques5
   1      2       3       1        3
   3      4       1       1        2
   2      2       2       1        2  
   1      1       3       4        1
   3      1       4       1        1
```

So from the above table data, I want to extract the count of each rating. For example the
count of 1 in the above table is 11 and the count of 2 is 6 and the count of 3 is 5 and so
on.. So I have to get the following table as my output

```
Count1  Count2  Count3  Count4
  11       6       5      3
```

I have some basic knowledge for incrementing count for that variable but I don't know how to navigate from one cell to another and check its value.

Answer (score 3):

In order to get the count across multiple columns, I'd suggest looking at unpivoting the data.  Since you are using SQL Server 2008+, you can use CROSS APPLY to convert your multiple columns into multiple rows. Once the data is in the rows, you can easily count the occurrences.

```
select
  sum(case when value = 1 then 1 else 0 end) Count1,
  sum(case when value = 2 then 1 else 0 end) Count2,
  sum(case when value = 3 then 1 else 0 end) Count3,
  sum(case when value = 4 then 1 else 0 end) Count4,
  sum(case when value = 5 then 1 else 0 end) Count5
from yourtable
cross apply
(
  values
    (1, Ques1),
    (2, Ques2),
    (3, Ques3),
    (4, Ques4),
    (5, Ques5)
) c (col, value);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b9537/1/0).

Note, this could also be written using the UNPIVOT function:

```
select
  sum(case when value = 1 then 1 else 0 end) Count1,
  sum(case when value = 2 then 1 else 0 end) Count2,
  sum(case when value = 3 then 1 else 0 end) Count3,
  sum(case when value = 4 then 1 else 0 end) Count4,
  sum(case when value = 5 then 1 else 0 end) Count5
from yourtable
unpivot
(
  value
  for col in (Ques1, Ques2, Ques3, Ques4, Ques5)
) un;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b9537/2/0)

If you don't want to UNPIVOT the data, you could also CROSS JOIN to a virtual table similar to:

```
select
  sum(case when DATA = 1 then 1 else 0 end) Count1,
  sum(case when DATA = 2 then 1 else 0 end) Count2,
  sum(case when DATA = 3 then 1 else 0 end) Count3,
  sum(case when DATA = 4 then 1 else 0 end) Count4,
  sum(case when DATA = 5 then 1 else 0 end) Count5
from
(
  select
    CASE s.col
      WHEN 'Ques1' THEN Ques1
      WHEN 'Ques2' THEN Ques2
      WHEN 'Ques3' THEN Ques3
      WHEN 'Ques4' THEN Ques4
      WHEN 'Ques5' THEN Ques5
    END AS DATA
  from yourtable
  cross join
  (
    select 'Ques1' AS col UNION ALL 
    select 'Ques2' UNION ALL 
    select 'Ques3' UNION ALL 
    select 'Ques4' UNION ALL 
    select 'Ques5'
  ) s
) s;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b9537/5/0)

All versions give the result:

```
| COUNT1 | COUNT2 | COUNT3 | COUNT4 | COUNT5 |
|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
|     11 |      6 |      5 |      3 |      0 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming #T is the original data table, you can use dynamic pivot to get your solution. Code below. As the code uses dynamic pivot, you can have any numbers in your table, not just 1, 2, 3 and 4; and get the results without altering the code.

```
--aggregate data into a single column and insert into a temporary table
select *  into #D from
(select Ques1 from #T
union all
select Ques2 from #T
union all
select Ques3 from #T
union all
select Ques4 from #T
union all
select Ques5 from #T) D;
go

--create dynamic pivot query to pivot the value count
declare @pivcols as varchar(200);

select @pivcols = stuff((select distinct '],[' + cast(Ques1 as varchar(10))
from #D
for xml path('')), 1, 2, '') + ']';

declare @pivcol_aliases as varchar(200);

select @pivcol_aliases = 
   stuff((select distinct ', Count' + cast(Ques1 as varchar(10)) + 
     '=[' + cast(Ques1 as varchar(10)) + ']'
from #D
for xml path('')), 1, 1, '');

declare @pivquery varchar(500); 

set @pivquery = 'Select ' +
@pivcol_aliases + '
from   
(select Ques1
 from #D
) as d
PIVOT
(count(Ques1)
for Ques1 in ( '+ @pivcols +' )
) AS pvt ';

--execute query
EXECUTE(@pivquery);
go
```